# Check if one cell contains the EXACT same data as another cell VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel Sheet with Column A and a Column B filled with data.

```
B    C       (columns)
1   1a       (row 1 is here)
2   3
3   4
4   4a
4a  5
5   5a
5a  6
6   6a
6a  6b
6b  10
10  11
11  12
12  13
13  14
14  15
15  16
16  16a
16a 16b
16b 16c
16c OUT
7   7a
7a  8
8   9
9   6
```

I want to say "If data in cell B7 equals the exact same data entered into cell O7, then execute statement. If it doesn't, go to next cell and retrieve that value, then [perform other statements]"

The problem with what I have tried, is that even if a cell has a "4" in it and I want to find the the cell starting with exactly "4a," it still starts with the cell that contains just "4" because there is a 4 in "4a"

Example:

```
For x = 7 
    If Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(x, 2).Value = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(7, "O").Value
        [execute statement]
```

If "O7" is set equal to "4a", it looks up the first value in B with a "4" in it instead of exactly "4a"

Is there a special function or command to make my code find the exact value and not just the first cell with part of the value in it?

Thank you.

Comment: It is O, the letter, as in the value in Cell "O7" Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Sadly, there is no such thing as [exact](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/EXACT-function-243e2bc1-93d6-4fd5-9608-dc3c5b8c046b) in Excel. See [Floating-point arithmetic may give inaccurate results in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/78113).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Strcomp()](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/strcomp.php)

`If StrComp (Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(x,2).Value,Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(7,"O").Value) = 0 Then ...`

When StrComp is 0, it means an exact match.

Comment: Thank you! It fixed it perfectly.

Comment: Hurray!  If you're going to be using those cell's values more than once, I recommend creating a variable and setting the values to that variable, it'll make the code a little easier to debug/read.

Comment: That is exactly what I did with those values inside the StrComp command. I am very new to excel VBA and haven't heard of that command yet, so thank you!